# Reference things from imported class in groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Say I have a `SomeThings.groovy` file:

```
def someVar = 'abc'
def someFunc(a) {
  a + 1
}
```

I start groovysh with the above file on the classpath and do:

```
groovy:000> import SomeThings
===> SomeThings
groovy:000>
```

All good. However:

```
groovy:000> someVar
Unknown property: someVar
groovy:000> someFunc(1)
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.someFunc() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
groovy:000>
```

How do I reference `someVar` and `someFunc` from groovysh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `SomeThings.groovy` as below:

```
//SomeThings.groovy
someVar = 'abc' // remove def to make variable available to shell
def someFunc(a) {
  a + 1
}
```

Then the file has to be `load`ed to shell as below (`load SomeThings.groovy` can also be used instead). :h or :help will show its usage.

```
groovy:000> . SomeThings.groovy 
===> abc
===> true
groovy:000> someVar
===> abc
groovy:000> someFunc(1)
===> 2
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Thanks dmahapatro! Any way not to have the variable values displayed when loading (i.e. the `===> abc` line after loading and such)?